# Select a row for each 'quantity'

Tags: mysql

Table:

```
Article | Quantity | pricePerUnit | order_id | article_id
--------|----------|--------------------------------------
     14 |        2 |        10.0  |        1 |    1
     X1 |        1 |         5.0  |        1 |    2
```

Expected output:

```
Article | Quantity | pricePerUnit | order_id
--------|----------|------------------------
     14 |        1 |        10.0  |     1
     14 |        1 |        10.0  |     1
     X1 |        1 |         5.0  |     1
```

What is a fast SELECT to populate the resultset with 1 row for each quantity per article?

Sorry I didn't *try* anything, I'm not sure wether this is possible at all. Self join.. would not be a help, grouping functions,..

Maybe `GROUP BY order_id, article_id, quantity` somehow..

Comment: I think the best option here would be to use a table with a load of rows and a single auto_increment ID that you can join onto where `Article.Quantity <= NumberList.ID` to multiply your row, then return a constant 1 as the quantity. I would like to know why you need this though, your request sounds very unusual and isn't generally the sort of thing you want to do.

Comment: I can't change the schema, there are a few TB of records in it. The customer needs a report which is... yea, quite unusual.

Comment: You don't need to change the table schema, just create a new table.

Comment: If there a max value of Quantity?

Comment: @Kickstart the max value of quantity is 3 ! Good comment

Comment: I would go with the solution by @peterm below, but with a max quantity of 3 it could be simplified further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** For the max quantity of **three** just do

```
SELECT Article, 1 Quantity, pricePerUnit, order_id
  FROM articles a JOIN 
(
   SELECT 1 AS n UNION ALL 
   SELECT 2 UNION ALL 
   SELECT 3
) n
    ON n.n <= a.Quantity
 ORDER BY order_id, Article
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4017a/3)** demo

---

**Original answer:** You can try

```sql
SELECT Article, 1 Quantity, pricePerUnit, order_id
  FROM articles a JOIN 
(
   SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 + 1 n
     FROM 
    (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
   ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
) n
    ON n.n <= a.Quantity
 ORDER BY order_id, Article
```

An inner select returns 100 rows meaning you can unpivot quantities up to the value of 100. If you need more update it accordingly.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4017a/1)** demo

---

Given that it is for a report and you have necessary right to create a new table it's best to substitute an inner select with a tally (numbers) table which you can create in the same manner:

```
CREATE TABLE tally (n int not null auto_increment primary key);
INSERT INTO tally
SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 + 1 n
  FROM 
(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
ORDER BY n;
```

And then your query will look like

```
SELECT Article, 1 Quantity, pricePerUnit, order_id
  FROM articles a JOIN tally n
    ON n.n <= a.Quantity
 ORDER BY order_id, Article
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70a63/1)** demo

Comment: Just beat me to it. One minor tweak would possibly be to remove the `ORDER BY n` as I don't think it is necessary here (as the number generated is not actually used).

Comment: @Kickstart Agreed. `ORDER BY` is not needed in this case.

Comment: Put `AS` between 1 and Quantity (it is to alias the returned value of 1 as a column called quantity)

Comment: @kickstart ah,... I used it wrong. It works!! Holy. What kind of wizzardry is this =)

Comment: It is a nice little trick for generating a range of numbers (1 per row). You can then cross join this range of numbers with your actual data to duplicate the rows as many times as you want. Same trick can also be used to split up a delimited string in a MySQL field.

Comment: Not only did it help me generating the report, I also learned something important. Thanks to both of you very much